# keypress event activates before keying and only once

Tags: javascript

I'm a newbie to javascript and just wrote a script which looks for keypress event and show the code .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            window.addEventListener("keypress",func(Event));
            function func(event){
                var x = event.keyCode ;
                alert("You have pressed : " + x );
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>Key Press Demo</body>
</html>
```

The function however is being called during window load and shows undefined and it is not working continously. Let me know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: `window.addEventListener("keypress", func);`

Comment: You just need to pass reference to the function when you bind it to the event `window.addEventListener("keypress",func);`

Comment: Thanks . It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter for `addEventListener` expects a reference to a callback function for the event, instead you are directly calling the function which is why it executes right away. Instead just pass `func`

```
window.addEventListener("keypress", func);
```